# rails joins models confusion (join many tables)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model

Here is my three models/tables

```
class Swimming::Classschedule < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :swimming_classtimes ,:class_name=>'Swimming::Classtime',:foreign_key => "classtime_id"  
  attr_accessible :id,:coach_id, :level_id, :note, :classtime_id
end


class Swimming::Classtime < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :swimming_classschedules,:class_name=>'Swimming::Classschedule'
  belongs_to :swimming_timeblocks ,:class_name=>'Swimming::Timeblock',:foreign_key => "timeblock_id"    
  attr_accessible :date, :end, :start,:timeblock_id,:id
end


class Swimming::Timeblock < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :swimming_classtimes,:class_name=>'Swimming::Classtime'
  attr_accessible :name,:id
end
```

I would like do an inner join

```
 select * from swimming_classschedules as c inner join swimming_classtimes as t on c.classtime_id = t.id inner join swimming_timeblocks as b on c.timeblock_id = b.id where c.date >= "2013-06-01" and c.date <= "2013-07-01" and c.timeblock_id = 5
```

and I would like to return all fields from these three tables not only from one table(say swimming_classschedules). I have read this page http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html but still not clear how to inner join with rails models

**UPDATE**

tried the first answer

```
Swimming::Classschedule.joins(:swimming_classtimes).joins(:swimming_timeblocks).select("swimming_classtimes.*,swimming_timeblocks.*,swimming_classschedules.*").where("swimming_classtimes.date >= '2013-06-01' and swimming_classtimes.date <= '2013-06-08' ")
```

got this error message

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'swimming_timeblocks' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: This will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/16442871/3767348

Answer (score 2):

Please try this, I'm having one doubt either we have to put the name of model with namespace in `join`

```
Swimming::Classschedule.joins(:classtime).joins(:timeblock).select("swimming_classtimes.*,swimming_timeblocks.*,swimming_classschedules.*")
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called: [joining nested associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).  Here's how you'd do it in your case:

```
Swimming::Classschedule.joins(:classtime => :timeblock).
select("swimming_classtimes.*,swimming_timeblocks.*,swimming_classschedules.*")
```

Hopefully the following will provide an additional example and illustrate what's going on above:
[image]